# Read Large data From SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

For a project I had to read unprocessed data from one server. After Reading I had to also update the reading data. It is time consuming as I need to read row by row. And update it accordingly. In main server, there are around 500-1000 rows inserted per second. I used to read the new data row by row. After reading, I processed that data and then update the row. Is there any other better solution for this. Because for processing there create a queue in database. plz advise ..

Comment: What is the average total number of rows that is processed per iteration? Are you using sql transactions? Evaluate whether the slow performance is due to individually transactioning each update operation. If that is the case, batch transaction your updates.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to process the data on the client? Maybe you should consider composing an update query or use a stored procedure to process the data on the server.

Comment: Ya, I need to process the data on client. Actually I need to do some calculation from other server, then I need to update...Thanks